# How to store small leaves like basil and mint for around 5 days to one week?

Tags: kitchen, storage

Normally, I find it really hard to store the mint and basil (I normally put them into my water pot to get the flavor).

My solution so far is to store them at the lowest part of my fridge but they got faded very quickly. Another way is to grow a small pot but it causes a burden to me to water it day after day.

I am looking for other solutions here
Please let me know if this question is not suitable here

Answer (score 3):

I've found freezing works well. In fact, there are companies, such as [Dorot](https://www.dorotgardens.com/), that sell frozen basil and dill. The commercial products use a liquid to make compact frozen spice cubes, but just putting fresh leaves in the freezer, in a container that seals well works well and keeps them for months. The only disadvantage is appearance, since freezing wilts them, but the taste is all there.

Comment: sound good, maybe I can put the mint in the freezer and see how it goes, thanks a heap

Answer (score 2):

Soak some paper towel with water and wrap the herbs in it. Place in a Ziploc bag in the fridge. Always keeps at least a few days for me, sometimes over a week depending on the herb.

Comment: THIS.   I was going to add it as a comment, but Luke already answered correctly.  Just a quick note - don't "soak" the paper towels as in dripping wet, but more than damp.  Thoroughly wet, with maybe 2-3 drops of water coming off.  If the towels start to dry after a couple of days, re-moisten them.

Comment: @Jason True... too much soaking and they disintegrate anyway. But too little and they need to be redampened after a couple of days. Luckily it's not too hard an art to perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

**How to store small leaves like basil and mint for around 5 days to one week?**

Try keeping them in cool, but not very cold water. At the same time, cut off a little bit off the ends of the shoots every day. This keeps the nurturing ability open in some plants. I know this works on some plants, such as roses, but not sure for basil and mint!

In any case, it is worth a try. My guess is it will work.